# Module is not in dependencies Intellij IDEA 2017.2.5 Java 9

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I just tested my java 9 module understanding in command line.
Then I moved to Intellij IDEA 2017.2.5 to test it. There I am facing the error `module is not in dependencies` Don't know why intellij is showing the error.

I just write required statements in `module-info.java` as `exports` and `requires`.

Then I use Intellij intelligence to solve the error self by IDEA. Just ALT+ENTER then I click on `Add dependency on module 'module-name-here'`.
But I don't know what Intellij doing behind the scene. Any idea about it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***But I don't know what Intellij doing behind the scene. Any idea about it?***

Its adding the modules to the module path of your current module. 
This is very similar to adding libraries/dependencies to classpath until Java8 to use the `imports`.

The same can be done manually using the following steps:-

```
~> Project Settings 
~> Modules > Select module you want to add dependency to
~> Dependencies > Add dependency
```

[image]

Comment: How I can add manually in intellij IDEA? and also why it is not adding automatically? why it showing the error and required ALT+ENTER to solve it.

Comment: @UnKnown Updated the answer.

Comment: "Add dependency" means to click the "+" icon in the bottom left, select "Module Dependency" and choose the module you need to depend on.